# How to Keep text from running off page when knitting to pdf?

Tags: r-markdown

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so I'm going to do my best to follow the guidelines.

My problem is that when I knit to pdf, I often can't keep the code from running off the page.

[code running off page in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X4ts.png)

I know that my first step is to look through previously asked questions, and I have found a few that address my question, but none of the answers in those questions worked for me.

I've tried the following:

1. adding  `options(width=X)`
2. adding {r, tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=X)}

Note that I tried a variety of different numbers for X in both of my attempts.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I understand you are wanting PDF output, but A LOT of times, the best alternative is to knit your document to HTML, and then print it to PDF from the web browser. This would probably fix your text width issue since HTML is a lot more dynamic, then once you print to PDF, you have a static file.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, for the tip about knitting to HTML and then printing as a pdf.  That did indeed fix the text width issue.  Much appreciated!  Also, thanks for your reference to the Rmarkdown Cookbook.

Comment: If I helped you, please upvote my comment and possibly answer. The rmarkdown cookbook isn’t even published yet, but definitely is gonna be full of great tips and tricks

Comment: Hey Daniel.  I upvoted your comment and answer, but since my reputation score is less than 15 (I just signed up for Stack Overflow a few days ago) it says that my votes were counted but won't be displayed publicly.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

An answer from [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/) is using a latex file. Your Rmarkdown YAML should look like this

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --listings
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
---
```

and then your *preamble.tex* file should contain this

```
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}
```

which would help wrap your text. This uses the latex package `listings`

[more documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/text-width.html)